# HTML5 video is blurry and low-contrast ONLY in my installation of Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, blurry, contrast

I am in Windows 7 x64, using Chrome 22. When I view an MP4 video in the video tag, it appears blurry and low-contrast compared to the source video viewed locally in Media Player Classic.

A screen-measuring app shows that both players are displaying the video at exactly its native dimensions (400x300).

This appears to be a problem only with my installation of Chrome. The video looks perfect on other machines, Macs and PCs alike. I have tried reinstalling Chrome, disabling all extensions, uninstalling my codec pack (CCCP), and reinstalling my codec pack, all to no avail.

```
<video src="http://d.pr/f/Nq6a+" width="400" height="300" controls ></video>​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9As8/)

[The video file](http://d.pr/f/Nq6a+)

Comparison screenshots from my end:

**Video tag in jsFiddle**

[d.pr/i/RqLW](http://d.pr/i/RqLW)

**Media Player Classic**

[d.pr/i/BZ69](http://d.pr/i/BZ69)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a video size issue. A little tricky but... try this:
http://webz.ro/blurry-html5-video/

Comment: This appears to have worked. It addresses both the blurriness and the bizarre grey tint in some instances of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any difference, but try removing the width/height attributes.

Comment: I tried, it didn't seem to change a pixel.
Do you mean that you don't see a difference in the screenshots, or did you download and compare the video yourself? If the latter, what's your browser/OS?

Comment: I just tried it. Viewed the video in VLC under Windows 7, viewed the jsfiddle in Chrome v22, both looked the same.

Comment: I think it is an issue within your browser, not a generally

Comment: I think you're right! I got to a couple other machines and it looks fine on them. Same version of Chrome. I've edited my question.

Comment: Perhaps you should try updating the video card drivers on your Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions - I tried everything and then some with no luck. However, since this has helped me discover that it's some kind of codec/software problem related uniquely to my setup, and not a "programming" problem, that makes it a whole new issue, so I'm going to mark this one as answered.

**Update**
See new accepted answer.